# Make Keydown(enter) trigger Ajax.ActionLink when selected whith tab index

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Could anyone help me out here?
I'm looking to trigger this(below) by just hitting the enter key:

```
<div id="create_new" tabindex="2">
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Create New",
    "create_new", new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId="accordion",
    InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<div id="create_new">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New",
"create_new", "controller_name", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "accordion",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
}, new { tabindex = 2}
)
</div>
```

Just have the tabindex in the link instead of the div.